# Configuring Lift with xsbt-web-plugin: finding the main method class

Tags: scala, sbt, lift

I'm attempting to create 'from scratch' a Lift web application and running into some difficulty. I started with [xsbt-web-plugin version 2.1](https://github.com/earldouglas/xsbt-web-plugin/blob/master/docs/2.1.md), and managed to get it working with a simple Jetty servlet. Then I tried to integrate information from the [Lift Cookbook](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000000030/ch01.html#_discussion).

This is my `build.sbt`:

```
organization := "ford.nathaniel"

name := "Lift From Scratch"

version := "0.1-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies += "javax.servlet" % "javax.servlet-api" % "3.0.1" % "provided"

enablePlugins(JettyPlugin)

libraryDependencies ++= {
  val liftVersion = "3.0-M8"
  Seq(
    "net.liftweb" %% "lift-webkit" % liftVersion % "compile",
    "org.eclipse.jetty" %  "jetty-webapp" % "9.2.1.v20140609" % "container, test",
    "org.eclipse.jetty" %  "jetty-plus"   % "9.2.1.v20140609" % "container, compile"
  )
}
```

I have a (one line) `project/plugins.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.earldouglas" % "xsbt-web-plugin" % "2.1.0")
```

I lifted the `Boot.scala` file directly from the above-linked Cookbook and placed it in `src/main/scala/bootstrap`, and similarly `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml`. I can run `sbt` from the command line, and it loads cleanly, but when I try `container:start`...

```
> container:start
[info] starting server ...
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Mar 3, 2016 9:52:25 PM
Error: Could not find or load main class 
>
```

I am unclear on how `sbt` is meant to find Lift's main class. I looked through a lot of older versions of `sbt` configuration, which differ because earlier versions use earlier versions of the xsbt plugin. (Specifically, you see things like `seq(webSettings :_*)` - what does that even do?) I pulled recent versions of `jetty-webapp` and `jetty-plus`, so I don't think that's the problem. On the other hand, none of those configurations make clear how Lift figures out where `Boot.scala` is, and in turn I'm not sure how to write the configuration such that it knows how to bootstrap the framework.

One main difference between the two sources is that the new Jetty README configures the servlet [like this](https://github.com/earldouglas/xsbt-web-plugin/blob/master/src/sbt-test/container/jetty-9/build.sbt):

```
libraryDependencies += "javax.servlet" % "javax.servlet-api" % "3.0.1" % "provided"

enablePlugins(JettyPlugin)

containerLibs in Jetty := Seq("org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-runner" % "9.2.1.v20140609" intransitive())

containerMain in Jetty := "org.eclipse.jetty.runner.Runner"
```

This seems to configure a [SettingKey](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Basic-Def.html) on the Jetty plugin, and point to the Jetty runner to kick off the servlet. However, given that I'm not running through a standard servlet, but through a filter configured to point to the Lift app in `web.xml`, this seemed like something I should remove.

Clearly I'm misunderstanding something. How do I diagnose why the `xsbt-web-plugin` is not picking up the Lift framework? It seems like either there is configuration-by-convention I can't find or I need to do something special with Jetty to point to the `web.xml` filter. Can anyone help clarify how to diagnose this, or elucidate how the two libraries should work together?

Comment: If I remember correctly Jetty was looking for `jetty-web.xml` rather than `web.xml`, unless you reconfigure it through code?. It's been a while.

Comment: I think this old project runs on Jetty just like you need: https://github.com/izmailoff/lift_authentication_starter. Check the xml files here: https://github.com/dahdahm/lift_authentication_starter/tree/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF. I'm not sure if it still compiles, but you might find exactly what you need.

Comment: @AlekseyIzmailov I have confirmed it works with the `web.xml` if using a simple servlet, just not with Lift. Do you have a link re:`jetty.xml`? It is mentioned in the documentation of `xsbt-web-plugin`, but as an 'add-on', so it seemed like there wasn't a concrete reason to go that route.

Comment: @AlekseyIzmailov The cited repo is on Jetty 8 (not 9.2.1) and Lift 2 (rather than 3). The `webSettings` bit in particular seems to have gone away in the later plugin version.

Answer (score 0):

The following `build.sbt` ended up working for me when executed as `jetty:start` (rather than `container:start`). It appears that `net.liftweb` needs to be included as a `libraryDependency` rather than in the `containerLibs`, and that the Jetty plugin manages the container. I don't understand particularly, though, what the difference is or how to diagnose this in the future (ended up just trying a lot of different things).

Notably, though, the `Boot.scala` class of Lift is picked up automagically if the `web.xml` file is set up to use a Lift filter.

```
organization := "ford.nathaniel"

name := "Lift From Scratch"

version := "0.1-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies += "javax.servlet" % "javax.servlet-api" % "3.0.1" % "provided"

//logLevel := Level.Debug

enablePlugins(JettyPlugin)

libraryDependencies ++= {
  val liftVersion = "3.0-M8"
  Seq(
    "net.liftweb" %% "lift-webkit" % liftVersion % "compile"
  )
}

containerLibs in Jetty := {
  val liftVersion = "3.0-M8"
  Seq(
    "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp" % "9.2.1.v20140609",
    "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-plus"   % "9.2.1.v20140609",
    "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-runner" % "9.2.1.v20140609" intransitive()
  )
}

containerMain in Jetty := "org.eclipse.jetty.runner.Runner"
```